# GCC, linker-script: Variables that resolve to manually defined addresses?

Tags: pointers, gcc, global-variables, indirection

I'll use a simple specific example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

file ***main.c***:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int X;

int main()
{
    printf("&X = 0x%zX\r\n", &X);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if it's possible (using a linker-script/gcc options) to manually specify an address for `X` at compile/link time, because I know it lies somewhere in memory, outside my executable.

I only want to know if this is possible, I know I can use a pointer (i.e. `unsigned int*`) to access a specific memory location (r/w) but that's not what I'm after.

What I'm after is making GCC generate code in which ***all*** accesses to global variables/static function variables are either done through a level of indirection, i.e. through a pointer (`-fPIC` not good enough because *static* global vars are not accessed via GOT) or their addresses can be manually specified (at link/compile time).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm after is making GCC generate code in which all accesses to
>   global variables/static function variables … their addresses can be
>   manually specified (at link/compile time).

You can specify the addresses of the `.bss` and `.data` sections (which contain the uninitialized and initialized variables respectively) with linker commands. The relative placement of the variables in the sections is up to the compiler/linker.

If you need only individual variables to be placed, this can be done by declaring them `extern` and specifying their addresses in a file, e. g. `addresses.ld`:

```
X = 0x12345678;
```

(note: spaces around `=` needed), which is added to the compiler/linker arguments:

```
cc main.c addresses.ld
```